# Shorter way of merging two JSON using python3.x

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

Here is a code that simply compare one's key with one's value. If they match, then inserts into 3rd array.

Is there any shorter way to reach this goal using single line for loop or lambda function?

```
a = {'a': '0', 'b': '0', 'c': '0', 'd': '0'}
b = {'ref1': 'a', 'ref2': 'b', 'ref3': 'c'}


def compare(a, b):
    res = []
    for m_keys in b:
        for d_keys in a:
            if(b[m_keys] == d_keys):
                res.append({
                    "dataElement": m_keys,
                    "value": a[d_keys]
                })
    return res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list` comprehension:

```
[{'dataElement': k, 'value': a.get(v)} for k, v in b.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{'dataElement': 'ref2', 'value': '0'},
 {'dataElement': 'ref3', 'value': '0'},
 {'dataElement': 'ref1', 'value': '0'}]
```